# Spring security - trigger event before every request

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, interceptor

I'm developing a java spring mvc project. I have a custom Interceptor class that extends `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`. In this class, I have a `preHandle` method that executes before any request. But the problem is, this method executes only when user is **authenticated**. In fact, when a guest user tries to execute some action, spring security redirects him to login page before executing `preHandle` method. My question is how can I execute some method before **any** request?

Answer (score 3):

You shoul simply use [servlet filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html), map it to every request, and list it so that it applies before the spring security filter